# Correct way to include files with a lightswitch application

Tags: office-interop, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I am using officeintegration with my lightswitch app to create a report from a docx template and that works great, but I need to manually copy the template file into my documents and then do this to get a location for the file:

```
string pathToMyDocs = Environment.CurrentDirectory.ToString();
string filelocation = pathToMyDocs + "\\InvoiceTemplate.docx";
```

I would rather the file was included with each client, and kept locally.
I can 'include' the file, but how do I then get a reference to the current running directory so I can use that file?

```
string pathToMyDocs = Environment.CurrentDirectory.ToString();
```

Doesnt seem to work.

Or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

string sourceFile = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/DocTemplates/EXH6.docx");

I hope this helps.